# Regex in java output results not matching

Tags: java, regex

I have this code

```
String pattern = "(\\.([a-z]*[A-Z]*|\\.)+)";
String input = "http://localhost-tes-folder.mySite.co.us:8080/";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

If I use http://www.regexr.com/ with this pattern: `(\.([a-z]*[A-Z]*|\.)+)` and this input I have this results:

```
.mySite.co.us
```

and if run this code i have this results:

```
.mySite
```

Can anyone help me to have the same results like output from regexr.com ?
Thanks.

Comment: `.folder.mySite.co.us` is wrong as your capturing group must start with a dot. There is no dot before `folder` in your example. Plus, this site use `/g` modifier, it means it will return all matches so `.mySite`, `.co`, `.us`. Check the value returned by `m.groupCount()`

Comment: Sorry, but I get no match on regexr.com (and not on my preferred regex tester http://regexpal.com either).

Comment: What are you actually trying to match? It looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) ;)

Comment: @Phillipp, don't forget to replace ` \\ ` with ` \ `

Comment: where i must replace double \\ with \ ? in java code ?

Comment: Try : `(?<=\.)([.a-zA-Z]*)+(?=:)` . It will match if sequence start with a dot and end with `:`.

Comment: Because \  is also a special character, so you need to escape it in order to actually use \

Comment: on a regex tester site, you can use simple ` \ ` but in java, you must escape those character, i.e. use a second `\ `

Comment: try this:  ((\\.[a-zA-z]*)+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
String pattern = "(\\.[a-zA-Z]*|\\.)+";
String input = "http://localhost-tes-folder.mySite.co.us:8080/";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/K3y39g)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will match 3 groups:

- `.mysite`
- `.co`
- `.us`

The `if` block will only print the first group. If you use a  `while` block the output will be the following:

```
.mySite
.co
.us
```

For the correct output you're looking for, you have to change the code with a `while` block and concat the output strings like this:

```
String pattern = "(\\.([a-z]*[A-Z]*|\\.)+)";
String input = "http://localhost-tes-folder.mySite.co.us:8080/";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
String output = "";
while (m.find()) {
    output += m.group(1);
}

System.out.println(output);
```

This will print:

```
.mySite.co.us
```

Otherwise you can change the pattern in order to recover all the chars after the dot and before the colon.

Comment: When concatenating a `String` in a loop, you should use a `StringBuilder` to avoid time loss. With your code, Java instantiates as many `StringBuilder`s as there are iterations (instantiating _is_ time-consuming).

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak a bit your regex to optimize it and make it faster.

Non-Java, it is `(\.([a-z]*[A-Z]*|\.)+)`.

- Your first group takes the whole of the line, so you don't need it → `\.([a-z]*[A-Z]*|\.)+` <sub>(Note the other group is not needed in Java, so you could make it non-capturing to make processing faster)</sub>
- `[a-z]*[A-Z]*` is repeated so order is not a problem and it can be reduced to `[a-zA-Z]*` → `\.([a-zA-Z]*|\.)+`
- The new first group allows at least one character which is a dot or a letter → `\.([a-zA-Z.])+` **This change has impact: the `|` allowed for breaking the matching at each dot. This version does not allow it**, but it matches your actual need. This removes the [need for a `while` and `String` concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30886235/1734119).
- Cleaning useless group again → `\.[a-zA-Z.]+`

So, adapting your code to use the new optimized version of the regex:

```
String pattern = "\\.[a-zA-Z.]+";
String input = "http://localhost-tes-folder.mySite.co.us:8080/";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

This prints:

```
.mySite.co.us
```

Be aware Regex are time-consuming and should be optimized when they can (e.g. no useless capturing groups